# C# check userid already exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am designing a web form to insert data into sql database.I just want to check that email id which is unique already exists or not.

code:

```
protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text))
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='C:\\Users\\aayush\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\WebSites\\JustDial\\App_Data\\Database.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select shop_email from shop where shop_email=@email", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox2.Text);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                Label1.Text = "email id already exists";
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

I tried above code but its not working i.e Label is not displaying anything.Any help will be thankful.

Comment: What exactly happens?

Comment: What you mean by *"its not working"* ??

Comment: You want to check if the user-id already exists but you are checking if the email exists. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: I am checking email id already exists or not.

Comment: i think you also need to add else statement so if user does not exist then assign different text to label

Comment: @user2125727: the title of your question suggests that you're checking the UserID, also the error message. **Edit** Not anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem :**  You are writing your code in `TextBox_TextChanged` Event handler so it would be invoked for everytime whenever there is a change in the `TextBox` and it would not give you the result untill unless you enter the complete `Email-ID`.

**Solution 1:** You need to write the above code in some Button Click Event handler as below:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{

//Write your code here

}
```

**Solution 2:** if you want to keep your code in the TextBox `TextChanged` Event handler but still want to identify the `EmailID` you can use `LIKE` operator instead of `=` operator

Try This:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select shop_email from shop
               where shop_email LIKE @email", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", "'%"+TextBox2.Text +"%'"+);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add else statement in case if user/email does not exist 
Also move this code to button click event or some other event. On Text Box text change event it will not return result.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='C:\\Users\\aayush\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\WebSites\\JustDial\\App_Data\\Database.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("select 1 from shop where UserID=@UserID", con))
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", TextBox2.Text);
    using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
       if (dr.HasRows)
       {
          Label1.Text = "userid already exists";
       }
       else
       {
          Label1.Text = "userid doesn't exists";
          //Create new user
       }
   }
}
```